# pandas problem when assigning value using loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So what is happening is the values in column B are becoming NaN. How would I fix this so that it does not override other values?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# %%
# df=pd.read_csv('testing/example.csv')
data = {
    'Name' : ['Abby', 'Bob', 'Chris'],
    'Active' : ['Y', 'Y', 'N'],
    'A' : [89, 92, np.nan],
    'B' : ['eye', 'hand', np.nan],
    'C' : ['right', 'left', 'right'] 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.loc[((df['Active'] =='N') & (df['A'].isna())), ['A', 'B']] = [99, df['C']]
df
```

What I want the results to be is:

| Name | Active | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abby | Y | 89.0 | eye | right |
| Bob | Y | 92.0 | hand | left |
| Chris | N | 99 | right | right |

Comment: The issue is that you're accidentally create an array from a ragged sequence (and you get warned about it). `df['C']` is a `Series` with values `['right', 'left', 'right']` while `99` is just single integer. So now in the backend you have something like `df[['A', 'B']] = np.array([99, ['right', 'left', 'right']])`. This is where NaNs come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this by creating a boolean mask using the condition: Where the `'Active'` column is `'N'` and the `'A'` column has missing values (`np.nan`). We can then use this mask to filter rows in the `DataFrame`.

First, we will replace the values in column `'A'` with `99` for rows where the mask condition is `True`. Then, replace the values in column `'B'` with the corresponding values from column `'C'` where the mask condition is `True`.

Following is the modified code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'Name' : ['Abby', 'Bob', 'Chris'],
    'Active' : ['Y', 'Y', 'N'],
    'A' : [89, 92, np.nan],
    'B' : ['eye', 'hand', np.nan],
    'C' : ['right', 'left', 'right'] 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
mask = (df['Active'] =='N') & (df['A'].isna())

df.loc[mask, 'A'] = 99
df.loc[mask, 'B'] = df.loc[mask, 'C']

print(df)
```

Now, the `DataFrame` will be updated correctly. Following is the output:

```
    Name Active     A      B      C
0   Abby      Y  89.0    eye  right
1    Bob      Y  92.0   hand   left
2  Chris      N  99.0  right  right
```

Comment: Good answer, but...  where is the `apply` function applied?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Thanks for pointing that out; I'll update the answer to avoid confusion. I thought about this for a while but I absolutely wasn't able to recall why I wrote it.